# Characters Geting Changed When Displayed - Character Set Issues with Italy and Poland

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, ftp

We are having a character set issue and have not been able to figure it out.  We have a server in a data center in Poland being used by some people in Italy.  Italy is FTPing the data to Poland in a flat file that is being read by a Java program and being inserting into an MS SQL server database.  The data is then being displayed on the web using an IBM IHS web server fronting an IBM WebSphere server.  The batch, database, web and app servers are all Windows boxes in Poland.

We are getting some instances of character substitution.  Specifically, the à (small letter A with a grace) is getting displayed on the web as an ŕ (small letter R with an acute).  We can see that the **à** in the CP1252 Western European character set, and the **ŕ** the CP1250 Eastern European character set occupy the same place (see http://www.kreativekorp.com/charset/), so we believe this is a character set issue.

The fields in the database are all nvarchar.  We have tried various setting for the field collation to no avail.  We tried setting the character set on the WebSphere app server JVM, but that did not help either.  The Poland server will be hosting sites for multiple countries in Europe, so changing the default language and character set in Windows is not really a good option.

Any clues would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Does data gets messed up only in the front-end or is it altered in the database also? It would be interesting to try to divide the problem to identify at which point data gets changed.

You can see a discussion about the JVM charset [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding/623036#623036).

Comment: The characters seem to get messed up on display. I have access to the database and wrote a simple java main to read and display the character. I can get the proper character to appear if I set this on the JVM: -Dclient.encoding.override=Cp1252 -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 and have the console output in the default Cp1250.  But if I change the console output to UTF-8, then the output is wrong.  This stuff is getting displayed on a web page that has UTF-8 encoding, so that is probably why it gets displayed wrong.  I can't change the web page encoding, so the challenge is to convert the data.